# How to replace XML queries in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a question about replacing XML columns, here is an small example about what I like to change.

```
<i><recipes n="0" />
<CGrecipes cg="4" r0="302053" r1="302084" r2="302049" r3="302068" />
<HArecipes ha="4" r0="302103" r1="302083" r2="302050" r3="302087" />
<KHrecipes kh="10" r0="302100" r1="302090" r2="302078" r3="302074" 
                   r4="302094" r5="302082" r6="302066" r7="302051" 
                   r8="302086" r9="302070" />
<KHNrecipes khn="10" r0="302102" r1="302089" r2="302056" r3="302077" 
                     r4="302052" r5="302069" r6="302081" r7="302073" 
                     r8="302093" r9="302085" />
<IMITARrecipes imitar="2" r0="302110" r1="302057" />
<MAUSERrecipes mauser="1" r0="302106" />
<SVDrecipes svd="1" r0="302059" />
<BLASERrecipes blaser="2" r0="302105" r1="302060" />
<SIGSAUERrecipes sigsauer="2" r0="302109" r1="302061" />
<HONEYBADGERrecipes honeybadger="1" r0="302062" />
<SMALLBACKPACKrecipes smallbackpack="1" r0="302095" />
<MEDIUMBACKPACKrecipes mediumbackpack="1" r0="302096" />
<MILITARYBACKPACKrecipes militarybackpack="1" r0="302097" />
<LARGEBACKPACKrecipes largebackpack="1" r0="302098" />
<TEDDYBACKPACKrecipes teddybackpack="1" r0="302099" />
<ALICEBACKPACKrecipes alicebackpack="1" r0="302112" />
<M82recipes m82="1" r0="302107" />
<AWMrecipes awm="1" r0="302108" />
<B93Rrecipes b93r="1" r0="302111" />
</i>
```

And I want to change it with a script to:

```
<i><recipes r="0" r0="302053" r1="302084" r2="302049" r3="302068" r4="302103" r5="302083" r6="302050" r7="302087" r8="302100" r9="302090" r10="302078" r11="302074" r12="302094" r13="302082" r14="302066" r15="302051" r16="302086" r17="302070" r18="302102" r19="302089" r20="302056" r21="302077" r22="302052" r23="302069" r24="302081" r25="302073" r26="302093" r27="302085" r28="302110" r29="302057" r30="302106" r31="302059" r32="302105" r33="302060" r34="302109" r35="302061" r36="302062" r37="302095" r38="302096" r39="302097" r40="302098" r41="302099" r42="302112" r43="302107" r44="302108" r45="302111" /></i>
```

I would like to get help and suggestions!

Comment: where is example?

Comment: fixed the empty example!

Comment: You should describe what you want to do in clear terms. You example does not make it any clearer.

Comment: I want to remove the <CGRecipes .... <IMITARrecipes.... all of them but I still want to keep the values inside them and rename r0....r1="ID" it has to count r0="ID" r1="ID".....

Comment: Close it pls, I found a solution in C++, so I dont need help anymore.

Comment: But thanks everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: Oh no you don't! I managed to do this in pure SQL. Pure, suffering SQL. I *will* have my answer posted. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Well, it couldn't be simpler (literally, I think), thanks to T-SQL's very limited implementation of XQuery, and the general hate for dynamic XML of any kind. Let `@xml` contain your XML in a variable (if it's a column, add a `FROM` as required).

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(XML, REPLACE((
    SELECT @xml.value('/i[1]/recipes[1]/@n', 'int') AS [@r], '' AS [@marker]
    FOR XML PATH('recipes'), ROOT('i')
), 'marker=""', (
    SELECT ' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE('r#="$v"', 
        '#', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1), 
        '$v', t.value('text()[1]', 'int')) 
    FROM (
        SELECT @xml.query('
            for $a in //*/@*[substring(local-name(),1,1)="r"] 
            return <r>{string($a)}</r>
        ') AS a
    ) _ CROSS APPLY a.nodes('r') AS x(t)
    FOR XML PATH('')
)))
```

From inner to outer: we unpack all the `r*` attributes into elements, attach a row number to them, then fold the result back into XML by lamely concatenating strings. For a finale, we transform the `n` attribute of `recipes` into `r` and substitute our string concatenation into the outer element.

Why is this code so terrible? Because the data model is terrible (well, and because SQL Server's implementation of XQuery is quite limited, omitting most advanced features that could simplify this). It's an abuse of XML in every way. Consider changing the attributes into child elements. Don't use concatenated element names like `ALICEBACKPACKrecipes`, generalize this to `recipes name='ALICEBACKPACK'` or suchlike. Think *static names* and *repeating content*:

```
<i>
  <recipes name="" value="0"></recipes>
  <recipes name="cg" value="4">
    <r>302053</r>
    <r>302084</r>
    ...
  </recipes>
  ...
  <recipes name="ALICEBACKPACK" value="1">
    <r>302112</r>
  </recipes>
  ...
</i>
```

This is far easier to query and process for anything that isn't a fully fledged programming language.

Comment: Even if the OP wanted to close this, your answer (and your hints!) are worth an upvote :-D